# PyQt4: QRadioButton inside a QWidget subclass with autoexclusive property

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

I've created a `QWidget` subclass called `RadioSpinButton`, in a Python application with PyQt4, it consists of a `QRadioButton` beside a `QSpinBox`. I'm using an instance of `RadioSpinButton` inside an horizontal layout with two instances of `QRadioButton`. The QRadioButton inside the new class have the same parent of the other two QRadioButtons, but its autoExclusive property doesn't work. How can I solved this problem? I need just one button checked but I have this:

[image]

[image]

**Code**

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class NewProject(QtGui.QWizard):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(NewProject, self).__init__(parent)

        # Iniciando páginas
        self.init_filepage()

        # Tamaño mínimo de la ventana
        #self.setMinimumSize(800, 600)

        # Título
        self.setWindowTitle(self.tr('Nuevo Proyecto'))

    def init_filepage(self):
        # Página para selección de imágenes
        self.addPage(FilesPage(self))    

class FilesPage(QtGui.QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(FilesPage, self).__init__(parent)

        # Título de la página
        self.setTitle(self.tr('Imagen'))
        self.setSubTitle(self.tr('Seleccione la escena alrededor de la cual se construirá el proyecto.'))
        #self.setPixmap(QtGui.QWizard.LogoPixmap, QtGui.QPixmap(":/app-icon.svg").scaledToHeight(48))

        # Elementos
        # Tipo de imagen según la cantidad de bandas
        imgtype = QtGui.QGroupBox(self.tr('Tipo de imagen (cantidad de bandas):'))
        imgtypelayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()

        imgPANtype = QtGui.QRadioButton(self.tr('PAN (1 banda)'), self)
        imgtypelayout.addWidget(imgPANtype)

        imgMSStype = QtGui.QRadioButton(self.tr('MSS (4 bandas)'), self)
        imgtypelayout.addWidget(imgMSStype)

        imgVartype = RadioSpinButton(self.tr('Variable'), self)
        imgtypelayout.addWidget(imgVartype)

        imgtype.setLayout(imgtypelayout)

        # Disposición principal
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(imgtype)

        self.setLayout(layout)    

class RadioSpinButton(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, text, parent=None):
        super(RadioSpinButton, self).__init__(parent)

        # Radiobutton
        self.button = QtGui.QRadioButton(text, parent)
        self.button.toggled.connect(self.change_spinbox)

        # Spinbox
        self.spinbox = QtGui.QSpinBox()
        self.spinbox.setEnabled(False)

        # Disposición
        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        layout.addWidget(self.spinbox)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def change_spinbox(self):
        self.spinbox.setEnabled(not self.spinbox.isEnabled())
```

Is this the proper way to design the `RadioSpinButton` subclass?

Answer (score 0):

Since all of your QRadioButtons don't have the same direct parent widget, I believe you are going to need to use a QButtonGroup: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qbuttongroup.html.

Comment: I've checked that they have the same parent widget. :(

Comment: Well, they clearly don't right? The QRadioButton with the spinner is a child of RadioSpinButton. My understanding is that QRadioButtons have to have the *exact* same parent for the exclusivity to work right. Otherwise, use QButtonGroup. EDIT - I see you are setting the parent of the QRadioButton in its constructor. Are you checking to see if that is still the case after you add them to the layout and set the layout? Regardless, QButtonGroup should fix it.

Comment: Ok, thanks! But why this occurs?: If I write `print imgMSStype.parent()` and `print imgMSStype.parent()` is the right places, the result of both is `<gui.dialogs.FilesPage object at 0x7f8673e0f938>` and `<gui.dialogs.FilesPage object at 0x7f8673e0f938>` respectively. In fact, if the RadioSpinButton is checked first and then you check one of the other it will be toggled just one time (the first time).

Comment: The `HBoxLayout` is going to parent it's widgets to the widget it is attached to – which is `RadioSpinButton`. But this will happen after the `self.setLayout(layout)` call. Not sure why it half-way works....

Comment: Thanks, David. Do you think that is a good way to implement the radio button with the spinner?

Comment: QButtonGroup doesn't work, it doesn't recognize `RadioSpinButton` as a right input parameter.

Comment: @osjerick. It will work, but obviously you need something like: `buttongroup.addButton(imgVartype.button)`.

Comment: @osjerick Can you update your question so it shows how you are using QButtonGroup?